# Can't turn on keyboard backlight

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, hp

my function key for turning on backlight is not working. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and HP OMEN 15. I tried xset led commands, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Fn+F5 to turn the backlight on or off?

Comment: @Terrance the problem is, that this fn key for turning on the backlight, doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it work if you boot to a LiveUSB?  Does it work if you still have Windows on your laptop and check in there?  Just need to eliminate software as the issue.  If it works in other OSes, then the issue could be a bug.  Also, driver support for Linux is up to the manufacturer of the hardware.  What kernel version are you running?  `uname -r`

Comment: I have windows dual boot and the keyboards works fine in windows but while starting ubuntu it works fine but when the lock screen appears the lights go off.

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem on Samsung computer that the FN Keys would not function. Plus the Nvidia driver would not allow to change the brightness as is.

And I'm not mistaken, your HP OMEN 15 also have nvidia graphical card.

So here something for you to try (instructions taken form the forum [Linux On My Samsung](https://loms.voria.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1091))

- Start "NVIDIA X Server Setting" from menu or type in a terminal:
  `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`
- Select "X Server Display Configuration" from the left hand menu.
- Push button "Save to X Configuration File".
- Push button "Show preview...".
- To the Device section, add the line `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`

It should look similar like this:

```
Section "Device"
       Identifier "Device0"
       Driver "nvidia"
       VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
       BoardName  "GeForce GT 330M"
       Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Then

- Uncheck "Merge with existing file".
- Save the file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
- Reboot and check if backlight control works. If so, you're done.

If does not work yet

- edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and change the line:

  ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   to
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
  ```
- Update grub with: `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot and backlight control should work.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work... I also tried [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/02/enable-fn-keys-hp-ubuntu-16-04/) to enable the fn keys, but that didn't work as well.